# Django rest framework unique together error message not displayed anymore

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I worked with django rest framework a lot and everything worked fine until today. The same function suddenly returns something different. I have a unique together on my client model with name and company. I recently created a mixin called AutoCompany which automatically sets the company on the client.

My client model:

```
class Client(AutoCompany):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["name", "company"], name="Name and company"),
        ]
```

AutoCompany

```
class AutoCompany(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey("company.Company", models.DO_NOTHING)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        company = apps.get_model("company.Company")

        try:
            self.company
        except company.DoesNotExist:
            self.company = get_request().user.company

        self.after_company_set()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def after_company_set(self):
        pass

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

So previously when I created a client with the same name for the same company I got a 400 response with this error:

```
The fields name, company must make a unique set.
```

My serializer looks like this:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Client
        fields = ["id", "name", "description"]
```

But now I just get a 500 response with a python error. It seems like the error is not caught anymore. Now I just get:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'test-cafd0ed10f9f4865a1d56abb67daa831' for key 'Name and company'")
```

Does anybody know why this change occurred?

Comment: Did you use `unique_together` before changing to `UniqueConstraint`?

Comment: @TomCarrick yes! That is exactly what I did. But I tried both and they both give the same result.

Answer (score 10):

DRF doesn't validate `UniqueConstraint`s the way it does `unique_together`.

The reason for this is because unique constraints can be more complex than just "this collection of fields must have unique values". Consider the following:

```py
UniqueConstraint(
    fields=["author", "slug"],
    condition=Q(status="published"),
    name="author_slug_published_uniq",
)
```

This constraint only validates that the row is unique if the status is `published`, i.e. there can be multiple rows with the same slug and author if they are all drafts. Because of this complexity, there isn't a validator for this. However, for this simple case, you can add [DRF's `UniqueTogether` validator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator) manually:

```py
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "name", "description", "company"]
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Client..objects.all(),
                fields=["name", "company"],
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I get a `KeyError: 'company'` probably because client adds the company based on the request and is not passed to the serializer. I'll add the serializer to the question.

The other weird thing is that I also tried it with using `unique_together` and it gave the same error. I think it is because of how I add the company (in the save method based on the request). But it should catch that ... right?

Comment: There's no validation in the `save()` method, so it won't validate. That's the same for any way of adding the unique constraint. If you want this to be validated, you should move this logic to the serializer.

Comment: Hmmm. It seems the validation is only done when company is set in the create function of the viewset. Which is unfortunate. Thanks for your information!